# Which quantum models violate the third law of thermodynamics and have an ergodic ground state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, lattice-model, ergodicity

Which any condensed matter quantum spin models over a finite lattice of size N which violates the third law of thermodynamics with ergodic mixings for the ground state?